# BizTalk Auto Deployment

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-deployment, biztalk-2013r2, btdf

I was able to build BizTalk applications using TFS automatic build but I am not sure how to do automatic deployment.I have tried BTDF but I am not getting how to do auto deployment using that.I am not able to find a suitable documentation/link for Auto Deployment of BizTalk solution.

Can someone shed some light for me on this?

I am using BizTalk Server 2013 R2.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, the hardest part of auto deploy scenarios is successfully running a silent install.

With BTDF, you would need to use PowerShell to script the steps that BTDF normally does internally.

There are a number of sample scripts out there if you search with "BTDF Silent Install".

Here is a sample from the TechNet Library: [Powershell Script to automate deployment of BizTalk Application using BTDF](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Powershell-Script-to-903a99c2)

Another option is to script the install with BTSTask.exe.